Trouble with topic monitor and rqt on ros2 foxy
I hope you are all well. I began dabbling with Robotis Ros a few weeks ago and just got my hands on a 2018 model turtlebot3 burger. It has a Raspberry Pi model 3b 1gb, 16gb memory, and hfs-lds-01 LiDAR for accessories. I followed the instructions on turtlebot3's website, downloaded Ubuntu 20.04, and decided to go with ros2 foxy. I ensured that everything was compatible and successfully ran teleop via SSH.
Pre: I did follow the instructions to "install lds-02 package" and in place of lds-02 package links, I used the lds-01 ones. I found this package on robotis github and am wondering if I needed to do this step in the first place. I would appreciate feedback on my decision here. It involved deleting the cartographer file and rebuilding.
Now I have a question. Under this section, I saw the turtlebot3 video for setting up the topic monitor and viewing it from rqt. Now I don't know if I'm wrong in understanding but was I supposed to run the ros2 bringup on the raspberry pi via ssh and then run rqt on my computer? This step is a little confusing as I tried to run rqt on my computer, then went into plugin > Topics > Topic Monitor, and could only see 2 topics in the monitor. I felt that it was obvious that I would only see these since my PI has the turtlebot topics running. So I tried typing rqt in the SSH and saw an error saying it is not installed in the Raspberry Pi.
Guys, please help me understand where I am going wrong. How can I view the topics on rqt on my computer while running turtlebot3 bringup on the Raspberry Pi? Without figuring this out, I cannot proceed to the SLAM section since it uses knowledge from here.
Thanks in advance!

Solved!
I was having trouble connecting the VM Ubuntu to the same internet network. By this, I mean the VM had a different IP address than the PC it ran on, so when I tried pinging it from the Raspberry Pi, I would not see any response.
To solve this, I created a partition on my laptop and sideloaded Ubuntu on the PC so that this version of Ubuntu would be connected to the network directly. It is a brute method of working out the error, but it worked, although I had to re-install all the files on the platform.
Everything works now; if you seem to encounter this issue, this is a guaranteed fix.
Cheers!
